# augdentity Haskell Implementation

Tags: haskell, recursion

NOTE: I'm not allowed to use any built-in functions
Given positive ints r and c indicating the number of rows and columns, create a 2D list that represents the "augmented identity matrix" with that dimension: It's the k x k identity matrix (where k = min(r,c)), and augmented rightwards or downwards as needed with zeroes in order to be of size r x c. Stated another way, it's an r x c matrix filled with zeroes that has ones along its main diagonal. I have to write this in both python and Haskell. I wrote the python solution but I'm kinda stuck on Haskell. The Haskell function has to be the following form:

```
augdentity :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
```

```
*Homework4> augdentity 3 3
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
*Homework4> augdentity 3 5
[[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0]]
*Homework4> augdentity 5 3
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
*Homework4> augdentity 2 2
[[1,0],[0,1]]
```

```
def augdentity(r,c):
    answer = []
    for row in range(0, r):
        newRow = [0] * c
        for col in range(0, c):
            if row == col:
                newRow[col] = 1
        answer.append(newRow)
    return answer
```

So I got this for my haskell function. Put zeros in list when x != y but I don't know how to put 1 when x == y

```
augdentity :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
augdentity x y = [[0 | y <- [1 .. y], x /= y] | x <- [1 .. x]]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `if ... then ... else`:

```hs
augdentity :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
augdentity r c = [[ if i == j then 1 else 0 | j <- [1..c] ] | i <- [1..r] ]

main = mapM_ (print . uncurry augdentity) [(3,3),(3,5),(5,3),(2,2)]
-- [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
-- [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0]]
-- [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
-- [[1,0],[0,1]]
```

Similarly, the python code could be simplified:

```py
def augdentity(rows, cols):
    return [[int(i == j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

for dim in [(3,3),(3,5),(5,3),(2,2)]:
    print(augdentity(*dim))
# [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
# [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
# [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
# [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```